# how to import a error log file into kibana

Tags: java, kibana

```
2016-01-20 13:03:29,652 INFO    OperationStudio.main:4857   Starting Studio
version: 10.20
build number: 49
revision: 62032
2016-01-20 13:03:29,765 INFO    LocalizedStringLookup.getMessages:313   URL for base bundle [StudioMessages]: file:/C:/OO/studio/languages/StudioMessages.properties
2016-01-20 13:03:30,497 INFO    OperationStudio.getKeyStorePath:7558    Could not find keystore file 'C:\OO\studio\.\var\security\certificate.p12'. Ignoring keyStore setting.
2016-01-20 13:03:30,642 INFO    StudioConfigurer$2.run:65   Initializing local engine spring context...
2016-01-20 13:03:30,642 INFO    StudioConfigurer$1.run:54   Initializing Studio spring context...
2016-01-20 13:03:33,426 WARN    GlobalSettings.loadGlobalSettings:118   Dozer configuration file not found: dozer.properties.  Using defaults for all Dozer global properties.
2016-01-20 13:03:35,780 WARN    UserPreferencesService.readPrefsHelper:106  Preference file 'C:\Users\pandad\.oo\opstudio.xml' does not exist.
2016-01-20 13:03:35,780 WARN    UserPreferencesService.readPreferencesFile:135  Reading from user preferences backup
2016-01-20 13:03:35,781 WARN    UserPreferencesService.readPrefsHelper:106  Preference file 'C:\Users\pandad\.oo\opstudio.xml.bak' does not exist.
2016-01-20 13:03:36,709 INFO    CertificateServiceImpl.initKeystoreHelper:63    Initializing truststore from file '.\var\security\client.truststore'
2016-01-20 13:03:36,729 INFO    StudioMavenConfiguration.init:39    ***** The local repository is C:\Users\pandad\.oo\data\maven *****
2016-01-20 13:03:36,730 INFO    StudioMavenConfiguration.init:40    ***** The remote repositories are [C:\Users\pandad\.oo\data\maven] *****
2016-01-20 13:03:38,441 INFO    PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties:172  Loading properties file from class path resource [Studio.properties]
2016-01-20 13:03:38,693 INFO    StudioConfigurer$1.run:56   Studio spring context initialized.
2016-01-20 13:03:38,982 INFO    OperationStudio.performTransformOfStudioOverridesToUuids:1017   Upgrading Studio overrides...
2016-01-20 13:03:39,043 INFO    OperationStudio.performTransformOfStudioOverridesToUuids:1039   Finished upgrading Studio overrides.
2016-01-20 13:03:39,076 INFO    LocalizedStringLookup.getMessages:313   URL for base bundle [DharmaMessages]: jar:file:/C:/OO/studio/lib/oo-dharma-commons-10.20.322.jar!/DharmaMessages.properties
2016-01-20 13:03:50,642 INFO    LiquibaseSlf4jLogger.info:42    liquibase Successfully acquired change log lock
2016-01-20 13:03:51,583 INFO    LiquibaseSlf4jLogger.info:42    liquibase Creating database history table with name: DATABASECHANGELOG
2016-01-20 13:03:51,591 INFO    LiquibaseSlf4jLogger.info:42    liquibase Reading from DATABASECHANGELOG
2016-01-20 13:03:51,594 INFO    LiquibaseSlf4jLogger.info:42    liquibase Reading from DATABASECHANGELOG
```

Comment: You have to use Logstash to import logs in the above-mentioned format. Logstash will output the results to Elasticsearch via which you can do visualizations on Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

There is another elastic tool to import logs into elasticsearch: logstash

Doc here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html